# Intellij IDEA custom constructor with setter

Tags: intellij-idea, constructor, customization, setter, code-snippets

Is it possible to create a custom generated constructor in Intellij IDEA.
I would like to use the setter methods by default to initialize the global class variables.

Instead of :

```
    public Person(long svnr, LocalDate geb, Geschlecht geschlecht) {
       this.svnr = svnr;
       this.geb = geb;
       this.geschlecht = geschlecht;
    }
```

like this:

```
    public Person(long svnr, LocalDate geb, Geschlecht geschlecht) {
        setSvnr(svnr);
        setGeb(geb);
        setGeschlecht(geschlecht);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no ready tool to generate constructors with setters in IntelliJ IDEA, please follow the issue created for this feature request:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-465